# How to convert a sql table to JSON or JSON to sql table in nodejs?

Tags: sql, node.js, json, typescript, postgresql

Have homework, task is to create currency converter app on nodejs.

I need to take data from the central bank and parse it. I thought, in order not to load the Central Bank server with requests, I need to send and separate data immediately to the database.

At the moment I can receive requests from the server and convert them from XML to JSON.

I'm tried this one.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'my-data-from-server';

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (json, '$.key-that-i-need')
WITH ( id int '$.key.id', ...);
```

But it get's error while declare @, if i delete first part and only do select it get's error on with.

There is also a question about how I can update the data when updating the data on the Central Bank website.

Comment: Where [in the Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find that syntax?

Comment: I'm find this in docs.microsoft in sql server - working with json data topic @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Why are you reading the SQL Server Manual when you are using Postgres? All JSON functions are [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: i'm new at all this stuff, i thinked all sql have same syntax @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: There is the SQL Standard, and just like programmers, every database has their own "standard". Advice, only use the manual for the database AND database version that you use. Anything else is kind of useless